# remove &nbsp; if is not in front one of this character !?:;%

Tags: preg-replace, whitespace, conditional-statements

I would like to remove all   if is not in front one of this character !?:;% with preg_replace ( I supose ) .

```
<div>&nbsp;Hello&nbsp;!
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
Am I 100&nbsp;% clear&nbsp;?&nbsp;</div>
```

It should give me

```
<div>Hello&nbsp;! Am I 100&nbsp;% clear&nbsp;?</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$str = preg_replace('/&nbsp;(?![!?:;%])/', '', $str);
```